# how add onclick button in adapter listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

My project contains listView(homelistView) that contains button(btnList).

When I click on button(btnList) it must go to another Activity. I tried a lot but I didn't find a good example.

Please suggest me a good example regarding this.
my button(btnList) on click is not working plz sujject my mistake & solution for it plz.. Thank u in advance.

**EDITED:**

At last after 2 days of struggle i got 70% of Output clearly SEE is this link  [button in listview adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650219/button-in-listview-adapter)

Its looks like this way

[image]

```
  --------------------------------A--
  text  text      button(btnList) B
  --------------------------------C---
  text  text      BUTTON(btnList) D
  --------------------------------E--
```

EfficientAdapter.java

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

private String mSections = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
ArrayList<Patient> patientListArray;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;
protected ListView mListView;
private int positions;
ViewHolder holder;


public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;

    String patientListJson = CountriesList.jsonData;
    JSONObject jssson;
    try {
        jssson = new JSONObject(patientListJson);
        patientListJson = jssson.getString("PostPatientDetailResult");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(patientListJson).getAsJsonArray();
    patientListArray = new ArrayList<Patient>();
    for (JsonElement obj : Jarray) {
        Patient patientList = gson.fromJson(obj, Patient.class);
        patientListArray.add(patientList);
        Log.i("patientList", patientListJson);

    }
}

/**
 * sorting the patientListArray data
 */
public void sortMyData() {
    // sorting the patientListArray data
    Collections.sort(patientListArray, new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Patient p1 = (Patient) o1;
            Patient p2 = (Patient) o2;
            return p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
        }

    });
}

public int getCount() {

    return patientListArray.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    
    this.positions = position;

    if (convertView  == null) {                     
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.homemplebrowview, parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mrn);
        holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.text4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        holder.text5 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        holder.text6 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wardno);
        holder.text7 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.roomno);
        holder.text8 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bedno);
        
        
        holder.btnList = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text1.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getName()));
    holder.text2.setText(patientListArray.get(position).getMrnNumber());
    holder.text3.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getRoom()));
    holder.text4.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getAge()));
    holder.text5.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getGender()));
    holder.text6.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getWard()));
    holder.text7.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getRoom()));
    holder.text8.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getBed()));
    

    //  holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(test));
    
    holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                   
            Toast.makeText(context, "STAT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent next = new Intent(context, Home.class);
            Log.i("next23", "next"+ next);
            context.startActivity(next);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}



      /*OnItemClickListener test = new OnItemClickListener() {
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
      ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId)).getText();

  {
//    Button btnList=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);
        
    btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        Toast.makeText(context, "STAT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent next = new Intent(context, Home.class);
        Log.i("next23", "next"+ next);
        context.startActivity(next);
    }

});
      }

         };
      */


static class ViewHolder {
    public Button btnList;
    public TextView text8;
    public TextView text7;
    public TextView text6;
    public TextView text5;
    public TextView text4;
    public TextView text1;
    public TextView text2;
    public TextView text3;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}



       /*public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, final int position,
          long arg3)
      {
    holder.btnList=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);
        
    holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        Toast.makeText(context, "STAT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent next = new Intent(context, Home.class);
        Log.i("next23", "next"+ next);
        context.startActivity(next);
    }

});
      }
        */



public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    // sorting the patientListArray data
    sortMyData();
    // If there is no item for current section, previous section will be
    // selected
    for (int i = section; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getCount(); j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                // For numeric section
                for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
                    if (StringMatcher.match(
                            String.valueOf(patientListArray.get(j)
                                    .getName().charAt(0)),
                            String.valueOf(k)))
                        return j;
                }
            } else {
                if (StringMatcher.match(
                        String.valueOf(patientListArray.get(j).getName()
                                .charAt(0)),
                        String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i))))
                    return j;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public Object[] getSections() {
    String[] sections = new String[mSections.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mSections.length(); i++)
        sections[i] = String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i));
    return sections;
}

    }
```

Comment: you may need to add `android:focusable="false"` on your button to get it worked.

Comment: see this tuts  [Custom listview with button](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Comment: try intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Comment: Transfer holder.btnList.setOnClickListener inside if(convertView == null)

Comment: @alezhka where i have to had this code in on click method or wt?

Comment: @userIsAMonkey I tried that also no useful trying from 2 days..

Comment: Could you explain "is not working"? Does it crash? Do you see the Log statement?

Comment: @sam here i explained my problem clearly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650219/button-in-listview-adapter

Answer (score 1):

This example may help you.

```
class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context con;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context con) {
        this.con = con;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) con
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homemplebrowview, parent, false);

        Button row = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);


        final int n = position;
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent next = new Intent(context, Home.class);
                    startActivity(next);

            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: got context rite... if (convertView  == null) { i have used this is it useful or not.. then what is difference between convertView  & rowview.

Comment: (1). this if condition is not needed I never used it and worked fine many times. (2). con is The object of Context I defined at top of the class.  (3). convertView is the methods parameter and rowview is the our created view from layout file.

Comment: Yikes! I prefer Rao's adapter, it's faster! There is no need to repeatedly recreate reusable resources, please watch Android's Romain Guy [discuss custom adapters](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html).

Comment: Android makes it easy to reuse custom rows by just implementing getItemViewType to return an int between 0 and number of types of rows. The convertView passed in is of this type or null. if (convertView == null) inflate....otherwise just set the Views to the appropriate values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make some changes like

```
private String mSections = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
ArrayList<Patient> patientListArray;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;
protected ListView mListView;
private int positions;
ViewHolder holder;
private Activity activity;
```

and in the constructor

```
public EfficientAdapter(Activity act) {
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
//this.context = context;
this.activity = act;
```

them in Intent change CONTEXT TO activity.

Hope it helps