# button in listview adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

can any solve my problem..  At last after 2 days of struggle i got 70% of Output clearly.  Exp: i have listview which data is coming from server..Inside Listview there is some text,button and scroll index A,BC,D,E,F,G.
Problem: button is not working  means when i on click on it... if add below code.
its looking some what below images:

HERE I HAVE USED IN XML IN THIS WAY---> com.woozzu.android.widget.IndexableListView
IN THIS CASE BUTTON ONCLICK IS NOT WORKING SCROLL VIEW A,B,C IS SHOWING IN correct manner and working fine..

[image]

**Status 1:-**

homempleb.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#335552"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout4" >                       
 <com.woozzu.android.widget.IndexableListView          
            android:id="@+id/homelistView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
            android:layout_weight="1.04"
            android:dividerHeight="0dip" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homempleb);
    Log.i("scan", " txtScanResult ");

    ActionItem nextItem = new ActionItem();
    final QuickAction quickAction = new QuickAction(this,
            QuickAction.VERTICAL);
    quickAction.addActionItem(nextItem);
    quickAction.setOnDismissListener(new QuickAction.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismissed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



   // listView = (IndexableListView) findViewById(R.id.homelistView);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.homelistView);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    listView.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
    objectAdapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);     
    listView.setAdapter(objectAdapter);
```

}

EfficientAdapter.java

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

private String mSections = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
ArrayList<Patient> patientListArray;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;
protected ListView mListView;
private int positions;
ViewHolder holder;


public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;

    String patientListJson = CountriesList.jsonData;
    JSONObject jssson;
    try {
        jssson = new JSONObject(patientListJson);
        patientListJson = jssson.getString("PostPatientDetailResult");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(patientListJson).getAsJsonArray();
    patientListArray = new ArrayList<Patient>();
    for (JsonElement obj : Jarray) {
        Patient patientList = gson.fromJson(obj, Patient.class);
        patientListArray.add(patientList);
        Log.i("patientList", patientListJson);

    }
}

/**
 * sorting the patientListArray data
 */
public void sortMyData() {
    // sorting the patientListArray data
    Collections.sort(patientListArray, new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Patient p1 = (Patient) o1;
            Patient p2 = (Patient) o2;
            return p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
        }

    });
}

public int getCount() {

    return patientListArray.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    this.positions = position;

    if (convertView  == null) {                     
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.homemplebrowview, parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mrn);
        holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.text4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        holder.text5 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        holder.text6 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wardno);
        holder.text7 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.roomno);
        holder.text8 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bedno);


        holder.btnList = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text1.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getName()));
    holder.text2.setText(patientListArray.get(position).getMrnNumber());
    holder.text3.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getRoom()));
    holder.text4.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getAge()));
    holder.text5.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getGender()));
    holder.text6.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getWard()));
    holder.text7.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getRoom()));
    holder.text8.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getBed()));


    //  holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(test));

    holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                   
            Toast.makeText(context, "STAT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent next = new Intent(context, Home.class);
            Log.i("next23", "next"+ next);
            context.startActivity(next);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}



      /*OnItemClickListener test = new OnItemClickListener() {
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
      ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId)).getText();

  {
//    Button btnList=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);

    btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        Toast.makeText(context, "STAT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent next = new Intent(context, Home.class);
        Log.i("next23", "next"+ next);
        context.startActivity(next);
    }

});
      }

         };
      */


static class ViewHolder {
    public Button btnList;
    public TextView text8;
    public TextView text7;
    public TextView text6;
    public TextView text5;
    public TextView text4;
    public TextView text1;
    public TextView text2;
    public TextView text3;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}



       /*public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, final int position,
          long arg3)
      {
    holder.btnList=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);

    holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        Toast.makeText(context, "STAT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent next = new Intent(context, Home.class);
        Log.i("next23", "next"+ next);
        context.startActivity(next);
    }

});
      }
        */



public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    // sorting the patientListArray data
    sortMyData();
    // If there is no item for current section, previous section will be
    // selected
    for (int i = section; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getCount(); j++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                // For numeric section
                for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
                    if (StringMatcher.match(
                            String.valueOf(patientListArray.get(j)
                                    .getName().charAt(0)),
                            String.valueOf(k)))
                        return j;
                }
            } else {
                if (StringMatcher.match(
                        String.valueOf(patientListArray.get(j).getName()
                                .charAt(0)),
                        String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i))))
                    return j;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public Object[] getSections() {
    String[] sections = new String[mSections.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mSections.length(); i++)
        sections[i] = String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i));
    return sections;
}

    }
```

**Status 2:-**

In this case Button on click is working fine  but scroll view A,B,C is also working fine but in side there will be no alphabetic A,B,C,D,E,F,G... 
IF I ADD listview in homempleb.xml, THEN BOTH WILL WORK FINE BUT NO ALPHABETIC INDEX LIKE SHOWN IN IMAGES. I want both button and scroll index work like above images.. i am not good in this topics. plz help me
 IT SHOWS IN THIS WAY:

[image]

homempleb.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#335552"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout4" >                      
     <ListView
            android:id="@+id/homelistView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
            android:layout_weight="1.04"
            android:dividerHeight="0dip" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how add onclick button in adapter listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637301/how-add-onclick-button-in-adapter-listview) Please don't ask the same question again. If you have something to add then edit the first question and add the new data/info.

Comment: @Luksprog this is different question. next time i do as ur comments..

Answer (score 4):

If somebody still cares:

The TouchEvent is catched by the index scroller.
<s>See https://github.com/denley/IndexableListView/commit/18210a54487ba079bb332fafec709e2de26883db</s>

Just change that few lines and you will be good.

Edit: I just checked out of curiosity. The link is dead. I guess the error is solved in recent versions (check out the [original IndexableListView project](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView) which was recently updated). I don't know what the changes were or even what the problem was anymore, so here are my working functions that imho could have been responsible for the problem, just in case:

IndexedListView.java

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (mScroller != null && mScroller.onTouchEvent(ev))
        return true;
    try{
    if (mGestureDetector == null) {
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(),

                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                            float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                        if(mScroller!=null){
                        mScroller.show();
                        }
                        return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
                    }

                });

    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(mScroller!=null){
    if(mScroller.contains(ev.getX(), ev.getY())){
        return true;
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    return false;
}
```

IndexedScroller.java

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (mState != STATE_HIDDEN && contains(ev.getX(), ev.getY())) {
            setState(STATE_SHOWN);
            mIsIndexing = true;

            mCurrentSection = getSectionByPoint(ev.getY());

            mListView.setSelection(mIndexer
                    .getPositionForSection(mCurrentSection));
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mIsIndexing) {

            if (contains(ev.getX(), ev.getY())) {

                mCurrentSection = getSectionByPoint(ev.getY());
                mListView.setSelection(mIndexer
                        .getPositionForSection(mCurrentSection));
            }
            return true;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (mIsIndexing) {
            mIsIndexing = false;
            mCurrentSection = -1;
        }
        if (mState == STATE_SHOWN)
            setState(STATE_HIDING);
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```