# Android: Adding a Button in a listview

Tags: android, listview, button

I'm trying to add a button in a list View, I searched a lot on google but nothing was good enough for me.

Here's my code: I have 2 classes :

Menu.java

```
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Menu extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

String[] listaMeniu = { "1", "2", "3"};
Button butonNota;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, listaMeniu));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener (this);

    Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
    btnLoadMore.setText("show me");

}
}
```

Menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/1" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize = "30dp"
    android:text="1" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

ListAdapter.java

```
     package com.example.a;

     import android.content.Context;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
     import android.widget.ImageView;
     import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Context context;
private String[] values;

public ListAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    super (context, R.layout.menu, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    }
```

}

I already made the list view, but I don't know how to add the button above the list. I tried to add it in menu.xml but it's shows up a button for every item in the list. Hope you guys understand what I want. 
Thank you!

Comment: you have to use custom listview..

Comment: learn base adapter.. instead of array adapter,

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637301/how-add-onclick-button-in-adapter-listview

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create your custom adapter. For example :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    Button buttonView = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonView.setText(values[position]);

    return rowView;
  }
}
```

And here is the xml from "rowlayout.xml". You have to put the layout file in the res/layout project folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="22px"
        android:layout_height="22px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then just update your Menu.java

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    String[] listaMeniu = { "1", "2", "3"};
    Button butonNota;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, listaMeniu));

        ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Stil not working. I want something like this:

| [picture] Item 1 
[picture] Item 2
....
[picture] Item 9

[Button] |

I made everything 'till the button and now i'm stuck. 
Can you explain me like for dummies :D ? Please!

Answer (score 0):

You need to override method getView in your adapter to return Button.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want your 10th item in the list to be a button.

That means that when you overwrite your ArrayAdapter class, you need to modify GetView() so it returns the button instead of a picture. Create two different layout XML files, rowlayout_picture.xml and rowlayout_button.xml, and then:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     View rowView = null;
     if (position < 10)
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout_picture, parent, false);
     else
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout_button, parent, false);

     return rowView;
 }
```